How to avoid mistakes with CORS gin?
Every now and then these errors with CORS appear, sometimes there are some, sometimes not, but always if there are, it looks like this:
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/u/profile/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

in one of the answers they write that you need to register all this on the server, but I have everything that is necessary registered:
func CORSMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, accept, origin, Cache-Control, X-Requested-With")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS, GET, PUT, DELETE")

        if c.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            c.AbortWithStatus(204)
            return
        }

        c.Next()
    }
}

logs on the server:
[GIN] 2024/08/02 - 22:07:32 | 200 |     945.525µs |             ::1 | GET      "/u/profile/"
[GIN] 2024/08/02 - 22:07:42 | 204 |      13.574µs |             ::1 | OPTIONS  "/u/profile/"
[GIN-debug] redirecting request 307: /u/profile --> /u/profile

script which send request:
document.getElementById('editProfileForm').addEventListener('submit', async function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const formData = new FormData(this);

            try {
                const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/u/profile/', {
                    method: 'PUT',
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
                    },
                    body: formData
                });

                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                }

                const data = await response.json();
                console.log('Profile updated successfully');
                const modal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(document.getElementById('editProfileModal'));
                modal.hide();
                fetchProfile();
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error updating profile:', error);
            }
        });

Looking at the logs, I thought that the problem was in the redirect, but after looking at the code, I realized that I am not doing any redirects, maybe I'm blind, but here is the server code:
func (ctrl *UserController) EditProfileController(c *gin.Context) {
    type changeProfileInput struct {
        Firstname string                `form:"firstname" validate:"max=20"`
        Lastname  string                `form:"lastname" validate:"max=20"`
        Age       uint8                 `form:"age" validate:"min=18,max=99"`
        Country   string                `form:"country" validate:"max=30"`
        City      string                `form:"city" validate:"max=30"`
        Bio       string                `form:"bio" validate:"max=500"`
        Hobbies   string                `form:"hobbies" validate:"max=100"`
        Photo     *multipart.FileHeader `form:"photo"`
    }
    currentUsername := c.MustGet("username").(string)
    var input changeProfileInput
    if err := c.ShouldBind(&input); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }

    err := utils.ValidateStruct(input)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }

    user, err := ctrl.userService.GetUserByUsername(currentUsername)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusNotFound, gin.H{"error": "User not found"})
        return
    }
    if input.Firstname != "" {
        user.Firstname = input.Firstname
    }
    if input.Lastname != "" {
        user.Lastname = input.Lastname
    }
    if input.Age != 0 {
        user.Age = input.Age
    }
    if input.Country != "" {
        user.Country = input.Country
    }
    if input.City != "" {
        user.City = input.City
    }
    if input.Bio != "" {
        user.Bio = input.Bio
    }
    if input.Hobbies != "" {
        user.Hobbies = input.Hobbies
    }  
    file, err := c.FormFile("photo")
    if err == nil {
        if _, err := os.Stat(config.UserPhotoPath); os.IsNotExist(err) {
            os.MkdirAll(config.UserPhotoPath, os.ModePerm)
        }

        filePath := filepath.Join(config.UserPhotoPath, fmt.Sprintf("%d_%s", user.ID, file.Filename))
        log.Println(filePath)
        if err := c.SaveUploadedFile(file, filePath); err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "Unable to save file"})
            return
        }
        photo := models.Photo{
            UserID: user.ID,
            URL:    filePath,
        }
        config.DB.Create(&photo)
        user.Photo = append(user.Photo, photo)
    }

    if err := ctrl.userService.UpdateUser(user); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "Unable to update user profile"})
        return
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"message": "Profile updated successfully"})
}

And if it's not difficult, then I would really like to know how to properly write functions where you need to change data in the database in Go, on any framework, I would be very grateful for your help!
I'm not very good at frontend, so I think the problem is in it, although there may be something on the server, in general, 2 days of searching for the problem were not successful, I can't even look at the logs. I wrote a log that immediately throws the server when calling the controller, but even it doesn't work.
Additional Information
All frontend javascript:
    <script>
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

        async function fetchProfile() {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/u/profile/', {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
                    }
                });

                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                }

                const data = await response.json();
                displayProfile(data);
                if (!data.user.lat || !data.user.lon) {
                    getLocation();
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching profile:', error);
            }
        }

        function displayProfile(data) {
            document.getElementById('name').textContent = `${data.user.firstname} ${data.user.lastname}, ${data.user.age}`;
            document.getElementById('bio').textContent = data.user.bio;
            document.getElementById('hobbies').textContent = `Hobbies: ${data.user.hobbies}`;
            const avatar = data.user.photo.find(p => p.is_preview) || data.user.photo[0];
            document.getElementById('avatar').src = `file:///home/wicki/.local/golang_projects/go_rest_api/${avatar.url}`;
            document.getElementById('countPhotos').textContent = data.count_photos;
            document.getElementById('place').textContent = `${data.user.country} ${data.user.city}`;
            
            window.userData = data.user;

            const photosContainer = document.getElementById('photos-container');
            photosContainer.innerHTML = ''; // Clear previous photos
            data.user.photo.forEach(photo => {
                const photoDiv = document.createElement('div');
                photoDiv.className = 'col-lg-6 mb-2 pr-lg-1';
                photoDiv.innerHTML = `<img src="file:///home/wicki/.local/golang_projects/go_rest_api/${photo.url}" alt="Photo" class="img-fluid rounded shadow-sm">`;
                photosContainer.appendChild(photoDiv);
            });
            console.log(window.userData)
        }

        function getLocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(saveLocation, locationDenied);
            } else {
                document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
            }
        }

        async function saveLocation(position) {
            const lat = position.coords.latitude;
            const lon = position.coords.longitude;
            document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = `Latitude: ${lat}<br>Longitude: ${lon}`;

            try {
                const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/u/save-location', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ lat, lon })
                });

                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                }

                const data = await response.json();
                console.log('Location saved:', data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error saving location:', error);
            }
        }

        async function locationDenied(error) {
            document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = "Geolocation permission denied.";

            try {
                const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/u/set-coordinates', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ error: "User denied the request for Geolocation." })
                });

                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                }

                const data = await response.json();
                console.log('Error set:', data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error setting coordinates:', error);
            }
        }

        function editProfile() {
            const modal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('editProfileModal'));
            const user = window.userData
            document.getElementById('firstname').value = user.firstname;
            document.getElementById('lastname').value =  user.lastname;
            document.getElementById('age').value =       user.age;
            document.getElementById('country').value =   user.country;
            document.getElementById('city').value =      user.city;
            console.log(document.getElementById('age'))
            console.log(document.getElementById('city'))
            document.getElementById('bio').value =       user.bio;
            document.getElementById('hobbies').value =   user.hobbies;

            modal.show();
        }

        document.getElementById('editProfileForm').addEventListener('submit', async function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const formData = new FormData(this);

            try {
                const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/u/profile/', {
                    method: 'PUT',
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
                    },
                    body: formData
                });

                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                }

                const data = await response.json();
                console.log('Profile updated successfully');
                const modal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(document.getElementById('editProfileModal'));
                modal.hide();
                fetchProfile();
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error updating profile:', error);
            }
        });

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            fetchProfile();
        });
    </script>

Server code which set up CORS middlware:
 func main() {

    config.Connect()
    router := gin.Default()

    // router.Use(cors.Default())
    router.Use(middleware.CORSMiddleware())
    router.GET("/docs/*any", ginSwagger.WrapHandler(swaggerfiles.Handler))
    routes.TestRoute(router)
    routes.AuthRoute(router)
    routes.UserRoute(router)
    routes.AdminRoute(router)
    go func () {
        if err := router.Run(":8080"); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("could not run sever: %v", err)
        }
    } ()
    if err := config.StartRedis(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}

If you can explain the reason and write a clear solution - you are holy people, because I am very annoyed by such a problem and it slows down my development in the field of full-stack developer.

Your log displays a GET request we aren't seeing. Are you sure that this is all the frontend code which sends relevant requests? Also, you didn't show how you actually set up the routes in Gin - so it's hard to tell whether the CORS middleware of yours is applied at the proper place, and whether something like a redirect triggered is by routes or middlewares. And last but not least, why aren't you using the default CORS middleware for GIn?

from origin 'null' implies that the request is likely being made from a file:///.... page

@NotX I edited my problem, answering your questions, I showed only the PUT request, but I didn't show the GET, because this crap happens when sending a PUT request. The router uses my middleware with CORS, I just didn't show it, so as not to clutter the question. And yes, I don't use the CORS middleware, because it has the same problem, and I think that such moments as sending requests from "files" are not taken into account there. But now please look, I took all your comments into account and edited my question.

@JaromandaX The problem shouldn't be with the "file:///" path, because everything is ok on the other pages.

weird how the browser is sending origin as null then

There are other cases where browsers include an Origin: null header in cross-origin requests: in particular, requests issued from a sandboxed iframe or from a document whose response's CSP contains a sandbox directive.

@jub0bs Have you any solution?

@wicki77 Not at the moment. You first need to figure out why the browser is including Origin: null in your client's requests.
